# if you're finished | passengers waiting for

Tags: adjectives

I have some questions about structures of sentences in pictures below

[image]

I think **finished** here is adjective but why don't we use **finish** simple verb instead?
And also in below picture, I don't have any clue about **waiting** at all !!!

[image]

What is the structure **will be departing**!!!?

Comment: As a learner, Aside from the fact that using "finish" is wrong, you can convey the same thing by several different ways. One of them is that adjective. Also, I cannot come up with anything more compact and beautiful than you're finished. For example, you can say if you have finished  or something. "will be departing" is the progressive future (tense).

Comment: Why finish is wrong? It doesn't make sense do you think

Comment: What do you mean? "you're finish" is wrong, isn't it?

Comment: so why not just "you finish"

Comment: finish what? Aside from the tense discussion.

Comment: "you are finished" is correct because "finished" is a past participle. It can't be "you finish" because that would be active present tense and there would be no linking verb "are". I further think that it would be better grammar to say "whether" there instead of "if", but people say it that way often. In essence, the past participle acts as an adjective; the main verb in this sentence is the linking verb ("is") since this is not passive, i.e. "You are angry because you are not done with this project."

Answer (score 2):

On top of Nick's comment, I'll add this. "Finished" is functioning as an adjective here (as Nick says). The structure is analogous to this one:

> I came by to see whether you are happy with the CD that I loaned you.

Where *happy* is an adjective. When you want to use a verb as an adjective, you use the past participle. Further examples:

> I came by to see whether you are done [satisfied, irritated, saddened, etc.] with the CD that I loaned you.

In your next picture, "passengers waiting for Flight 774" are passengers *who are* waiting for Flight 774. The *who are* is implied and understood. Also, *will be departing* is an example of the future progressive tense, which you can read about [here](http://www.really-learn-english.com/future-progressive.html).

Future progressive is used for an activity that is ongoing at some point in the future. Compare these:

> I will be studying all evening.
>   I will be walking for most of the afternoon.
>   At midnight, I will be sleeping.

with these examples in the future tense:

> I will begin studying after dinner.
>   I will start walking by 2 p.m.
>   I will go to sleep at 11 p.m.

Your particular example could read *your flight will depart at 11:30*, too. But use of future progressive suggests that the departure will be ongoing at 11:30, which implies that the process of departing isn't an immediate one.

Whether departure implies a single point in time depends on how you look at it: if the plane is considered to "depart" at the time they shut the doors, that would suggest use of the future tense. If the departure consists of several steps, such as getting the passengers on board, taxiing down the runway, getting clearance, and taking off, that suggests future progressive. Since both are essentially true, you can use either tense.